# Blank icons in start menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

There are no start menu icons showing up for my programs. This is a standard vs2010 setup project for a winforms project. I have set the icon for each start menu shortcut in the setup project's file system window, each executable has it's icon manifest set. The icons appear in windows explorer. I have recreated the setup project from scratch, didn't help. This used to work. Nothing I have tried today has fixed this it doesn't make sense. Any ideas appreciated.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced this once quite some time ago, but frankly don't recall the exact cause right away - two things come to mind:

- Icons can come in a wide variety of both size and color depth, so maybe you have chosen a combination of formats within the [ICO file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29) which doesn't cover the required formats for the particular version and/or configuration (color/dpi) of Windows you are using currently? Here are some resources:

  - The [Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx) section within the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx), specifically [Color and saturation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx#color) and [Size requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx#size) - please be aware of section *For high dpi* in particular.
  - [Creating Windows XP Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx#winxpicons_overview), which is definitely outdated, but still provides some useful insights regarding the respective Windows (Explorer) defaults, see e.g. [Icon Design Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx#winxpicons_overview).
- *Update* - the following doesn't seem to apply here as per your comment: <strike>Another association is triggered by your statement *each executable has it's icon manifest set*: There could be an issue with 32 vs. 64 bit handling here, insofar Windows *might* pull all sorts of magic regarding respective executable treatment, e.g. regarding a 32 bit executable o a 64 bit host etc.</strike>

I'll try to dig further and recall my specific experience, but maybe this can provide some ideas for further exploration on your side already.

Good luck!

Comment: It's working now. I think the problem has something to do with the various combined formats inside the ico file. I must have finally generated the right one, I use an icon generating program.